# menu structure design

Tags: java, mysql, menu, javafx-2

I'm working with java + javafx + mysql and I need to develop a menubar for my application.
When the application starts, I have to build the menu based on the user role.

I'm using one table to store the menu hierarchy structure.

```
| MENU_TABLE |
| ---------- |
| ID_MENU    |
| PARENT_ID  |
| TITLE      |
```

And another table to store a reference to de fxml file wich I need to load when the user selects the associated menu item.

```
| MENU_FORM_TABLE |
| --------------- |
| ID_MENU         |
| FXML PATH       |
```

I don't like so much this approach, is very hard to maintain, I have to be very careful when I need to add a new menu o to modify an existing one.

Any other ideas ? Suggestions ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

without more info on what you mean by hard to maintain, this looks like a simple design that is not very hard to maintain.

when you insert/update/delete on "MENU_TABLE", you should do the same on "MENU_FORM_TABLE".
(and in delete, you can define a forign key in the table "MENU_FORM_TABLE" using the cascade option over the field "ID_MENU" so that when a row in "MENU_TABLE" is deleted, the corresponding row in "MENU_FORM_TABLE" is deleted too automatically by the db).

Still, as it looks, the relation here is one to one. therefore, you can move the field "FXML PATH" to the first table and drop the second table totally. this will allow you to work on one table only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something that allows you to "visualize" the menu hierarchy structure more easily.
One way to do it is to define the hierarchy/nesting structure in JSON.  You can then write a generator program (perhaps in JavaScript) to generate SQL statements to populate your tables.